# I was trying to do acronym in haskell (with a space at front ), but some work some do not work, I don't know why

Tags: haskell

```
goal2 s = newstring s
where
newstring [] = []
newstring (h : m : t)
  | h == ' ' && m /= ' ' = m : newstring t
  | h /= ' ' && m == ' ' = newstring t
  | m == ' '             = newstring t
  | otherwise            = newstring t
```

- Ok, one module loaded.
- `ghci> goal2 " apple pen pen pen" "appp"`
- `ghci> goal2 " pen pineaple appen pen" "pp*** Exception: assign1_task1.hs:(103,5)-(108,42): Non-exhaustive patterns in function newstring`
- `ghci> goal2 " pen pineapple apple pen" "ppap"`

Comment: What is the plan for a string that contains exactly one character?

Comment: Turn on warnings, observe the compiler complaining about the pattern `_ : []` not being matched.

Comment: I only want the first letter for each word, those are just the conditions I gave.

Comment: newstring [] = []
  | otherwise            = newstring t

the compiler complain about this two lines

Comment: @EthanLim: you forgot to implement the case where the string contains *exactly one* character, so `newstring [x] = ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to implement the case where the string contains *exactly one* character. If you perform recursion, where we each time move two steps further, then eventually we will end at the empty string (list), or a string (list) with one character.

You thus should consider this with:

```
goal2 :: String -> String
goal2 [] = []
goal2 [x] = …
goal2 (h : m : t)
  | h == ' ' && m /= ' ' = m : goal2 t
  | h /= ' ' && m == ' ' = goal2 t
  | m == ' ' = goal2 t
  | otherwise = goal2 t
```

where I leave implementing the `…` part as an exercise.

You `goal2` will however still not work with `" pen pineapple appen pen"`, since the cursor will stop at:

```
 pen pineappleappen pen
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
```

This will result in `ppn`. This is because you each time move the cursor two places, whereas if a space is encountered, you might want to move the cursor a single place such that it can inspect the next character. This will also make your function simpler, and thus less error-prone.

Comment: I have answered your exercise with [h]=[h], and yea the result is 'ppn'. Due to only six hours of learning, can you give me some time about how to get the next letter of 'head'.I've only learnt  how to retrieve the 'head' and all the 'tail' letters.

Comment: @EthanLim: work with a pattern `goal2 (h:ts)`, to move the cursor one item to the right if you recurse on `ts`.

Comment: @EthanLim: another wy to make only one hop is with `goal2 (m:ts)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
goal2 s = newstring s
 where
   newstring [] = []
   newstring [h] = []
   newstring (h : t)
   | h == ' '             =  head t : newstring t
   | otherwise            =  newstring t
```

Thanks once again dude.@Willem Van Onsem

- ghci> goal2 " pen pine apple pen"
  "ppap"
- ghci> goal2 " pen pen pen pen pen"
  "ppppp"